# Use owen storage server instead one drive in Office365

Tags: cloud, office365, onedrive

I want to switch to office365. I am going to use all its features except OneDrive, because the clients don't want that their files be on the cloud. So is there a way to point on other storage server instead office365.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I believe they can use something called OneDrive for Business. I think they need a SharePoint server to host it though.

> If you’re using Office 365, you get 1 TB of space in the cloud for OneDrive for Business. If your OneDrive for Business library is hosted on a SharePoint server in your organization, your organization’s administrators determine how much storage space is available.

Below is the link where I found it.

[What is OneDrive for Business?](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-OneDrive-for-Business-187f90af-056f-47c0-9656-cc0ddca7fdc2)

Comment: I want that documents be in my owen servers and doesn't synchronize with one drive.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, not that I have heard of.
The whole point of 365 is that everything is in the cloud. The only things that would be spread across on-prem and cloud would be an Exchange server running in Hybrid.